# How To Detect "Enter" Keypress in Reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Given the following code:

```
  [:input {:type "text"
           :value (:text @app-state)
           :on-change (fn [e]
                        (if (= 31 (.-keyCode e))
                          (println "ENTER")
                          (println "NOT ENTER")))}]
```

How to change the `if` condition so that enter keypresses can be distinguished from normal keys? All properties in `e` except `target` seem to be null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

that's how to fix it:

1. you should listen to `:on-key-press` (rather than `:on-change`),
   because "enter" doesn't trigger `:on-change` event (it obviously doesn't change the text)
2. key code for "enter" is **13**, not **31**
3. use `charCode` instead of `keyCode` (not an expert in js, but `keyCode` doesn't work for me in firefox)

   ```
   [:input {:type "text"
            :value (:text @app-state)
            :on-key-press (fn [e]
                            (println "key press" (.-charCode e))
                            (if (= 13 (.-charCode e))
                              (println "ENTER")
                              (println "NOT ENTER")))}]
   ```

Comment: `charCode` is deprecated, `key` is [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

Answer (score 10):

With `key`.

```
[:input
 {:on-key-press
  (fn [e]
    (if (= (.-key e) "Enter")
      (.log js/console "Enter")
      (.log js/console "Not Enter")))}]
```

Also of interest is `:on-key-up` and `:on-key-down`.

Comment: This is great, didn't know about `.-key`. You can also save one character by using `js/console.log`. :^)